# How to use if elseif else with 'between' in where clause all together .Please provide suitable example

Tags: database, oracle

```
 1 select resort.resortid,resort.resortname,review.comments from
 2 resort inner join review on resort.resortid=review.resortid
 3 case
 4 if starrating between in 5.0 and 4.5 then
 5     {print "Excellent Resort"}
 6 
 7 else if starrating between in 4.4 and 4.0 then
 8     {print "Very Good Resort"}
 9     
10 else
11     {print "Good Resort"}
12     
13 end if
```

Comment: This is the query as per my basic knowledge

Answer (score 0):

For the sample query in your post (and using Oracle 11gR2), you may be able to add `starrating` as an additional column using the case statement. Is that what you intended?

```
select 
    resort.resortid,
    resort.resortname,
    review.comments ,
    case when starrating between 4.5 and 5.0 then 'Excellent Resort'
         when starrating between 4.0 and 4.4 then 'Very Good Resort'
         else 'Good Resort'
    end as rating
from resort 
    inner join review 
    on resort.resortid=review.resortid
;
```

To include margin values (4.5, 4.0 etc.), modify your SQL as:

```
select 
    resort.resortid,
    resort.resortname,
    review.comments ,
    case when starrating >= 4.5 and starrating < 5.0 then 'Excellent Resort'
         when starrating >= 4.0 and starrating < 4.4 then 'Very Good Resort'
         else 'Good Resort'
    end as rating
from resort 
    inner join review 
    on resort.resortid=review.resortid
;
```

SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e2d4/3)

Comment: I'm getting error as "from keyword not found where expected"

Comment: @SP45 have you seen the sample in [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e2d4/1)? Post your SQL that's giving an error

Comment: case when starrating between  5.0 and 4.5 then 'Excellent Resort'
     *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: 1 select resort.resortid,resort.resortname,review.comments
    2 case    when starrating between  5.0 and 4.5 then 'Excellent Resort'
    3      when   starrating between  4.4 and 4.0 then 'Very Good Resort'
    4      else    'Good Resort'
    5 end as    starrating
    6 from Resort inner join review on Resort.resortid=review.resortid;

Comment: @SP45 are you forgetting a comma (,) after review.comments in the selected list of columns? what prevents you from copying the SQL from the fiddle, to avoid errors? e.g. your values for the between clause are not in the correct order - e.g. it ought to be between 4.0 and 4.4 - if this works, feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work/65088#65088) and/or [vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments/173400#173400)

Comment: ohh..thanks i forgot a comma before case statement..Now its working fine

Comment: actually , i'm not getting complete output ..as resort having exact 4.5 starrating is completly being ommited from the output..what should be done ..as both values of 'between' are inclusive

Comment: @SP45 i've included an alternative in the answer